# Unique features of Vim over more "modern" text editors like Sublime?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, vi

I'm working on a presentation about vi/Vim. I'd like to highlight some of the features that they have over newer editors, especially Sublime Text. Many of the differences can be equalized by adding plugins, but here's my current list of out-of-the-box functionality that appears to be unique to vi/Vim:

- vi is available on the vast majority of Unix machines, including servers
- ports are available for just about every operating system, including mobile
- [blockwise-visual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#CTRL-V) editing
- diff viewer built in
- spell checking built in
- multiple registers (a.k.a. "clipboards")
- Vim is free software, open source, charityware

Are there any other unique built-in features I'm overlooking?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is mainly opinion based, and it will be likely be closed.

Comment: I've changed the wording from "selling points" to "features" to remove the opinion aspects.

Comment: Advantage is quite ambiguous, but it seems the way you have reworded the text is a bit more neutral, so I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 7):

This is opinionated question and I expect the question to be closed. However there are many facts about features editors have and do not have. Instead of focusing on what other editors do not have I will focus on what Vim does have. Here is a list of features that I find important.

Relatively unique to Vim:

- Modal editing
- Built-in help see `:h`
- Terminal UI
- Extensive OS support
- Open source
- Undo-branches (:h undo-branches)
- Persistent undo
- `.` for simple redo
- Shares many common commands with ex and sed
- Uses buffers (try opening up 100 files w/ tabs and see how that works out)
- Built-in file exploring and remote editing (`:h netrw`)
- Built-in diff support
- Window splitting and tab support (same buffer can be multiple places)
- Run commands over many buffers/windows/tabs: `argdo`, `bufdo`, `tabdo`, and `windo`
- Command line editing (`:h cmdline-window`)

Features that many other editors share:

- Advanced repeat with macros
- Plugins and scripting
- Quickfix list - keeps older lists (:h `:colder`)
- Location list - quick fix for a specific window
- Visual Block mode - many other editors have this however `$` is still pretty special (`:h v_$`)
- Built-in grepping (`:h :vimgrep`)
- Zero width regex atoms e.g. `:h /\zs`
- Many completion modes: word, line, tag, spelling, syntax, and omni. Plus you can create your own.
- Easy to create alternate key mappings
- Registers - your clipboard
- Jumps/marks: see `:h ctrl-o`, `:h g;`, `:h ctrl-t`, `:h mark-motions`
- Customization fold with foldtext

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, every editor/IDE comes with spell checking and many of those "modern" editors you speak about also have blockwise-selection and some even have non-contiguous selection which Vim doesn't.

A few *facts*, from the top of my head:

- runs in the shell *and* as a GUI,
- modal editing,
- an intuitive editing language,
- text-objects and motions for super precise high-speed movement,
- a steep learning curve that guarantees many aha moments for years

Comment: +1 for that last bullet point :D

Answer (score 0):

The one and only advantage that no one can discut is the fact that vi will **always** be available when you connect on a distant machine which does not have a GUI. There are other shell editors, but none is as universal as vi is.

Just 4 days ago, I had to install a software on a distant VM which did not run a GUI, the fastest way to set the configuration files was to just fire-up vi, make the change and save.

Had I not know how to use vi, I would have had to get a copy of the file locally, edit it in a "modern" editor, then re-upload it.

Comment: This is a good argument for knowing the basic vi commands but not necessarily to use vi/vim as your primary editor for everything.